# Rails AJAX loads entire page into 'update' div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I wanted some code that would automatically reload the posts and insert them into the div post_container:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Update", {:action => 'ajax_update', :id => @posts, :update => 'post_container'}, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

This rails snippet in my home.html.erb actually takes the entire page (title, head, body tags) and places it inside of the div post_container. Why? Also, as far as I can tell, the ajax_update function doesn't even get called.

How would I do what I am trying to do? And why is this entire page loading happening? I'm using Rails 2.3.11

(edit: also, there is no confirm dialog when you click the link.)

EDIT 2:
the html output of the code snippet:

```
<a confirm="Are you sure?" href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('post_container', '/home', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('uaqM0Ie8to5pprvE6WcF416DN0vNeyO7Xa+JM6VZFY4=')}); return false;">Update</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way to do it:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Update",:update => 'post_container', :url => {:action => 'ajax_update', :id => @posts, }, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

Based on information from the Rails 2.3.11 API documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002185

Also, the periodically_call_remote method found on that page is also useful for automatic calls that don't require clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action, use :layout => false

```
def ajax_update
  @posts = Post.find(@posts)
  render :layout => false
end
```

Comment: The action never seems to get actually get called. I've added the html output to the question if you'd like to take another look